# Can the solution to this ODE be generalized to higher order polynomials or more general input functions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials

I have an analytical solution to an ODE parametrized by two quadratic polynomials and want to know if there also are solutions for more general input functions:

Given the two functions $f_1$ and $f_2$, I want to interpolate them with a factor $y$ (the unknown of the ODE), i.e.
\begin{align}
f(x) &= y(x) f_1(x) + (1-y(x)) f_2(x) \\
&= y(x) (f_1(x)-f_2(x)) + f_2(x)
\end{align}
subject to the conditions
$$
\frac{f'(x)}{x} = e,
$$
where $e \in \mathbb{R}$ is a constant.

This leads to the following ODE:
$$
e = \frac{1}{x}(y'(f_1-f_2) + y(f_1'-f_2') + f_2').
$$
To complete the ODE, I have chosen the initial condition $y(x_0) = 1$ for a constant $x_0$.

The concrete functions $f_1, f_2$ I have are quadratic polynomials, and I can solve the problem using WolframAlpha if I enter the problem with corresponding coefficients. See below for the solution.

Now, my question is, can I solve the problem analytically for

1. arbitrary higher order polynomials $f_1, f_2$
2. general functions without further assumptions?

---

To solve for quadratic polynomials, define $f_1(x) = a_1 x^2 + b_1 x + c_1, f_2(x) = a_2 x^2 + b_2 x + c_2$, and simplify the differences as $a := a_1-a_2, b := b_1-b_2, c := d_1-d_2$. Then, for the input ($g := x_0$, otherwise WA gets confused)

```
e = 1/x * (y'(x)*(a*x^2 + b*x + c) + y(x)*(2*a*x+b) + 2*a_2*x+b_2 ), y(g)=1
```

WolframAlpha computes the following solution:
$$
y(x) = \frac{2 a_2 (g^2 - x^2) + 2 a g^2 + 2 b_2 (g - x) + 2 b g + 2 c - e g^2 + e x^2}{2 (ax^2 + bx + c)}.
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general solution of your differential equation is
$$ y \left( x \right) ={\frac {1}{{f_1} \left( x \right) -{f_2}
 \left( x \right) } \left( {\frac {e{x}^{2}}{2}}-{ f_2} \left( x
 \right) + C \right) }
$$
where $C$ is an arbitrary constant.  Of course for this to work with an initial value at $x=x_0$, you need $f_1(x_0) \ne f_2(x_0)$.

Comment: Thank you! Can you comment on how to arrive at this?

Comment: Put $(y (f_1 - f_2))' = y' (f_1 - f_2) + y (f_1' - f_2')$ on one side of the equation, and integrate.